# How to publish messages using an external webhook in cloud pub/sub?

Tags: cloud, cloud-computing

I have an external webhook already present. I want to publish messages in cloud pub/sub whenever an event occurs which triggers the external webhook.

I am new to cloud pub/sub and couldn't find any relevant documentation on how to achieve the above scenario.